# Pull subscription running on subscriber anonymously. Determine when replication has ended

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I created a publication (snapshot or transaction) on a Server-A. I'm trying to set up pull replication on Server-B.

I'm able to use replication properly but my snapshot is very big & the complete transaction takes around 1 hr to complete.

When I check my subscription status on subscriber, it says Job agent is already started & running. On publisher server I get status is "No replication transaction". Even when I know replication is working in the background on Subscriber.

I end up starting SQL Profiler on subscriber server to watch when replication has ending. Is there any other way to watch this?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: those statuses sound normal

Comment: Yes, this is normal & it is working in background. But i can't see what exactly is happening in background in case of pull subscription. While i generally see replication happening in case push subs. am I comparing wrong?

Comment: I think there should be a way to findout distributor to subscriber status. I checked with event trace but it doesn't work until my snapshot is not completely replicated on subscriber.

Comment: i've never used pull subscriptions. only transactional/push.. synchronization status on the subscription usually lets you know if it's updating.. also running profiler on the publisher showed the replication transactions

Comment: Agreed! same i have done. 

So Is there no other way to see if it updating on subscriber?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, what you are looking for is not really possible with snapshot replication and here is why; the publisher has a job that creates a snapshot of the database and saves it to your chosen folder.  On the secondary (subscriber) there is a job that goes out to the publisher's folder and processes it.  For instance, you can have the publisher set to run the job at 6 am and have your subscriber later process the file at 8 am.  The only purpose of the publisher is to save a snapshot file and doesn't care when the subscriber processes it.

However, transactional replication is different from snapshot where both the publisher and subscriber can be monitored for latency (what I believe you are expecting for snapshot); reason, the publisher has a log reader job that is continuously sending changes to the distributor database.  While that is happening, the subscriber has a job that continuously processes those changes from the distributor.

Here is a link to [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565(v=sql.105).aspx) explaining the various flavors of replication.

Hope this helps!